# Magento2 - How do I write below query function into non-deprecated? without using getCollection()

Tags: magento2, query, dependency-injection, dependency

How do I write below `function` into `non-deprecated`? In Magento2. without using getCollection()

```
 public function getNewCustomer()
    {
        $customerData = $this->customerFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $customerData->addAttributeToSelect("*");
        $currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // Y-m-d h:i:s
        $newDate = strtotime('-30 MINUTE', strtotime($currentDate));
        $newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newDate);
        $customerData->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => $newDate]);
        $customerData->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $currentDate]);
        $customerData->load();

        return $customerData;
    }
```

Please help
I changed below, but its not work

```
public function getNewCustomer()
{
    $customerData = $this->customerFactory->create();
    $customerData->getSelect()
         ->where(
            'created_at >= ?',
            $customerData->getConnection()->getDateSubSql(
                new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'),
                '30',
                AdapterInterface::INTERVAL_MINUTE
            )
        );

    return $customerData;
}
```

Comment: which dependency you are using for "$this->customerFactory" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model class `getCollection()` is equivalent to **Resource  Collection Class**.

Suppose Model class `\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer` and its resource Collection Class `\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection`

Instead of  `\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer->getCollection` You can use `\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection`

```
<?php
namespace {NameSpace};

class OrderTest
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $customerCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerCollectionFactory = $customerCollectionFactory;
    }
    public function hello()
    {
        /**
         * @var  \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection $customerCollection
         */
        $customerData = $this->customerCollectionFactory->create();
        $customerData->addAttributeToSelect("*");
        $currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // Y-m-d h:i:s
        $newDate = strtotime('-30 MINUTE', strtotime($currentDate));
        $newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newDate);
        $customerData->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => $newDate]);
        $customerData->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $currentDate]);
        $customerData->load();
    }
}
```